# BLoC builder doesn't rerender UI

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc, freezed, flutter-freezed

I would like to get todos from API, set them to state and show them on screen.
On initState method I am starting request. After recieving it in my BLoC, I set it in state. But todos don't visible on my screen and state is emty array.

**My request from screen:**

```
@override
  void initState() {
    todosBloc.add(TodosInitialFetchEvent());
    super.initState();
  }
```

**Here is my BLoC file with state:**

```
@freezed
abstract class TodosState with _$TodosState {
  const factory TodosState({
    required List<Todo> todos,
    @Default(false) bool loading,
  }) = _TodosState;
}

class TodosBloc extends Bloc<TodosEvent, TodosState> {
  TodosBloc() : super(const TodosState(todos: [])) {
    on<TodosInitialFetchEvent>(todosInitialFetchEvent);
  }

  FutureOr<void> todosInitialFetchEvent(event, Emitter<dynamic> emit) async {
    emit(state.copyWith(loading: true)); // try to set loading as true
    List<Todo> todos = await TodosRepo
        .getAllTodos(); // async operation to JSON placeholder API (works)
    emit(state.copyWith(
        todos: todos, loading: false)); // finish loading, apply recieved todos
    print(state.todos); // shows todos which were recieved
  }
}
```

**Part of UI screen where I should see todos, but no:**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: BlocBuilder<TodosBloc, TodosState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        print(state.todos); // shows empty array
        if (state.loading) {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
```

Comment: you should provide Todo class also. and be sure that 
print(state.todos); // shows empty array

- triggered twice on loading: true and loading: false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that I shouldn't create another instanse of bloc to call an event

Was:

```
final TodosBloc todosBloc = TodosBloc();
```

Should be in initState:

```
context.read<TodosBloc>().add(event);
```